# How to get total number of repeated objects and respective keys from a python dictionary having multiple objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python dictionary which consists of many nested dictionaries. I.e. it looks like this:

```
result = {
    123: {
       'route1': 'abc'
       'route2': 'abc1'
        },
    456: {
       'route1': 'abc'
       'route2': 'abc1'
        },
    789: {
       'route1': 'abc2'
       'route2': 'abc3'
        },
    101: {
       'route1': 'abc'
       'route2': 'abc1'
        },
    102: {
       'route1': 'ab4'
       'route2': 'abc5'
        }
```

}

Here we can see that `123`, `456` and `101` has the same values.
What I am trying to do that is to find out the repeated object which in this case is:

```
{
   'route1': 'abc'
    'route2': 'abc1'
 }
```

and the keys which have this repeated object i.e. `123`, `456` and `101`.
How can we do this?

Along with repeated objects info, I also want to know which objects does not repeat. I.e. `789` and its respective object and `102` and its respective object.

PS: Please note that I don't really know beforehand which objects are repeating as this structure will be generated inside code. So, it's possible that there could not be any repeated object or there could be multiple i.e. more than one.
Also, I can not use `pandas` or `numpy` etc. due to some restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a dictionary holding all the matching keys for each distinct value in your `result` dict (where the values are themselves dicts). This is a fairly common pattern in Python, iterating through one container and aggregating values into a dict. Then, once you've created the aggregation dict, you can split it into duplicate and single values.

To build the aggregation dict, you need to use each subdict from `result` as a key and append the matching keys from the original dict to a list associated with that subdict. The challenge is that you can't use the subdicts directly as dictionary keys, because they are not hashable. But you can solve that by converting them to tuples. The tuples should also be sorted, to avoid missing duplicates that happen to pop out with different ordering.

It may be easier to understand just by looking at some example code:

```
result = {
    123: {'route1': 'abc', 'route2': 'abc1'},
    456: {'route1': 'abc', 'route2': 'abc1'},
    789: {'route1': 'abc2', 'route2': 'abc3'},
    101: {'route1': 'abc', 'route2': 'abc1'},
    102: {'route1': 'ab4', 'route2': 'abc5'}
}

# make a dict showing all the keys that match each subdict
cross_refs = dict()
for key, subdict in result.items():
    # make hashable version of subdict (can't use dict as lookup key)
    subdict_tuple = tuple(sorted(subdict.items()))
    # create an empty list of keys that match this val
    # (if needed), or retrieve existing list
    matching_keys = cross_refs.setdefault(subdict_tuple, [])
    # add this item to the list
    matching_keys.append(key)

# make lists of duplicates and non-duplicates
dups = {}
singles = {}
for subdict_tuple, keys in cross_refs.items():
    # convert hashed value back to a dict
    subdict = dict(subdict_tuple)
    if len(keys) > 1:
        # convert the list of matching keys to a tuple and use as the key
        dups[tuple(keys)] = subdict
    else:
        # there's only one matching key, so use that as the key
        singles[keys[0]] = subdict

print(dups)
# {
#     (456, 123, 101): {'route2': 'abc1', 'route1': 'abc'}
# }
print(singles)
# {
#     789: {'route2': 'abc3', 'route1': 'abc2'}, 
#     102: {'route2': 'abc5', 'route1': 'ab4'}
# }
```

Comment: Awesome!
Seems like exactly what I was looking for.
And thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: No problem! Hope it works well -- I wasn't sure what final form you wanted.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. However, I might need to convert `keys` of `dups` from tuple to list or even merge both `dups` and `singles`.

Comment: That should be pretty easy to do, working from this. Let me know if you run into any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in result.items():
    d[tuple(v.items())].append(k)

desired = {
   'route1': 'abc',
    'route2': 'abc1'
 }
d[tuple(desired.items())]
```

Output:

```
[456, 123, 101]
```

For not-repeated items, use list comprehension:

```
[v for v in d.values() if len(v) == 1]
```

Output:

```
[[102], [789]]
```

Comment: I like that. But how would he find the most common object? I am having trouble with the dicts not being hashable.

Comment: @Carsten Most common as in the one with most number of repeated items?

Comment: Yes. In this case `{'route1': 'abc', 'route2': 'abc1' }`.

Comment: Use `max`: `max(d, key=lambda x:len(d.get(x)))`. Output: `(('route1', 'abc'), ('route2', 'abc1'))`

Comment: Okay, but this means you transferred the dicts to a tuple or set structure?

Comment: @Carsten Yes. It is, nevertheless, very easy to convert it back to `dict`. Just use `dict(max(d, key=lambda x:len(d.get(x))))` will give you exactly what you want: `{'route1': 'abc', 'route2': 'abc1'}`

Comment: @Chris I can not provide `desired` object. Because I don't really know which objects are repeated. It could be one object or more than one.

Comment: @HamidArrivy Have you tried the `max` method in the comments? If you feel that is something you are looking for, I'll edit the answer with a bit more explanation

Comment: @Chris `max` will give that object which is being repeated the most. e.g. if one object is being repeated 2 times and another one 5 times. It will give that one will repeat 5 times. Actually, I want to get all the repeated objects. Not just the common one. Also, I am not sure how the list comprehension works here as `len` will always be 2 and not 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `drop_duplicates()` function of `pandas`:

Firstly transforme your dict on dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd `

df = pd.DataFrame(result).T
```

Output :

```py
    route1  route2
123 abc     abc1
456 abc     abc1
789 abc2    abc3
101 abc     abc1
102 ab4     abc5
```

Then use the function `drop_duplicates` and transform to a dict

```py
df2 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['route1', 'route2']).T.to_dict()
```

Output :

```py
{
 123: {
       'route1': 'abc', 
       'route2': 'abc1'
      },
 789: {
       'route1': 'abc2',
       'route2': 'abc3'
      },
 102: {
       'route1': 'ab4', 
       'route2': 'abc5'
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
But, I can not use pandas or numpy etc. due to some restrictions.